# C# Convert integer to ASCII byte

Tags: c#

```
int i =5;
byte j[2];
```

Above is what I have. I want 5 to be equals to hex 0x35 which is '5' in ASCII. How do I write to convert so that `j[0]= i = 0x35`  ?

Comment: did you check out the BitConvertor class ?

Answer (score 1):

Just type "ascii" in a google query and take the first hit, you'll see that digits have an offset of 48.

The somewhat heavy-handed but always correct way is to use the Encoding class:

```
 byte[] j = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(i.ToString());
```

which gets you an array with a length of 1, the proper outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `0x30` to `i` and cast the result to `byte` again:

```
j[0] = (byte)(i + 0x30);
```

Comment: I've try this but it's error: cannot implicitly convert 'int' to 'byte'.

Answer (score 0):

you can use char/int arithmetic for that

```
j[2] = '0' + (byte)i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
j[0] = (byte)('0' + i);
```

That makes it so that when i is 0, it will be just i, and for every increase of i, it will increase as well.

Comment: I've try this but it's error: cannot implicitly convert 'int' to 'byte'.

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET doesn’t use ASCII for its string encoding, the “proper” way of doing this is a bit roundabout:

```
byte[] result = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(i.ToString());
```

(This needs to have the `System.Text` namespace imported.)

Since the ASCII encoding is pretty straightforward (i.e. corresponds to .NET’s internal character encoding for the first 127 code points) you can also cheat and use the method proposed in the other answers (i.e. either add `'0'` or `0x30` and explicitly convert to `byte`).

Comment: @RuneFS See the second paragraph. You can also do it via the manual route. That said, going via the .NET `Encoding` class is beneficial if you need to do that for more than just a single-digit number and it has the advantage that the whole conversion is encapsulated in one well-tested method, ready for use.

Comment: well the second paragraf wasn't there when I commented :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `char`. It solved a related problem.

```
char A = 'A';
char B = A++;
```